# Task Manager shows more processes than I have running

Tags: windows-7, windows, process, task-manager

I have ~50 processes running but the total processes in Task Manager shows 100+ always. What is causing this? And how can it be fixed?

Comment: How do you know that tasmgr is wrong? Run ProcessExplorer.exe as admin and compare both outputs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: I have 16 instances of chrome.exe in my Task Manager. So it would be reasonable to have over 100 processes if you have a lot of application running.

Comment: What were the results of using ProcessExplorer? Please update your post with screenshots and more info so we can better help.

Comment: Also how did you determine that first number, "~50" ? If you were just using Task Manager to check.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are processes you know should not be there, 100+ processes is not abnormal. I have just outlook and chrome running currently with 103 processes active.